# xModRedirect works differently on apache 2.2 vs. apache 2.4 how to make work on 2.2?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4, apache2.2

Does anyone know the differences between apache 2.2 mod_rewrite and apache 2.4 rewrite!

I have a web builder app and it works great, but I want to migrate the code from an apache 2.4 server to an apache 2.2 server.

When I do I get a recursive loop on the rewrite rules on the 2.2 server:

Here is the .htaccess code that WORKS on an apache 2.4 server

```
    # Powered by Domainsunder.ca
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.cgi index.html
    ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized"
    ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden"
    RewriteEngine On

    #### PERSISTENT CONTENT ####

    #### PERSISTENT CONTENT END ####

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sitepro/$1 [L,QSA]

    #### PERSISTENT CONTENT ####
```

So when I run it on apache 2.2 it loops infinitely and errors out:

```
    Thu Feb 11 17:04:03 2016] [error] [client x.x.x.x] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://www.domainsunder.ca/
```

so I added

```
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
```

on the apache 2.2 .htaccess, but it still has the wrong URL as in http://somedomain.ca/sitepro/mypage instead of http://somedomain.ca/mypage

The error message on the screen NOW is:

```
    The requested URL /sitepro/domain_name_information/ was not found on this server.
```

The file sitepro/index.php is supposed to render the page and it works on apache 2.4.

The mod_rewrite and .htaccess allow seem to work so this appears to be an apache engine issue.

What do I need to add to make this work?

I also had the same problem trying to get Wordpress to work on this same 2.2 server.

I do not want to run cpanel or recompile apache on this centOS 6.x box .

Comment: yes - I have edited it to a more clear version.

Comment: Yes the .htaccess is in the root directory

Comment: That is the full .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] The mod_rewrite was working great: the problem was the sub directory's /sitepro/.htaccess was not properly transferred in ftp.